# finding out sudo password on ssh server

Tags: ssh, sudo

I need to do a sudo command on a ssh server.

It asks for password

```
[sudo] password for myname:
```

but it's apparently different from the password for ssh server itself.

Can sudo only be used by root?

If not, should I ask the maintenance people for the password?

Or is there a way to set it up myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See : http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html

Specifically see rootpw, targetpw , etc.

It is possible to have two different passwords, one for the account and another for the sudo command.

You should ask to the Maintenance people....